# Oracle select specific rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Can we select specific rows to range in oracle? for example, I have a table of 100 rows I have to select only a range of 10 to 20-row numbers. Is it possible to do that

Comment: what is the logic to give numbers to the row?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the first row --- or the tenth row -- unless a column specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with an auxiliary operation. Firstly number the rows by `row_number()` function and then order by them :

```
  select * from  
  (
   select row_number() over (order by 0) rn, t.*
     from tab t
   )
  where rn between 10 and 20;
```

but this is **not** a **stable** operation, since SQL statements are **unordered sets**. Therefore it's better to define a unique identity column and order depending on it.

Replace zero in the order by clause with some columns of your table to be able to reach a rigid ordering criteria. If a primary key column exists, it might be better to include only it in the order by list.

Comment: I think using ROWNUM would be even easier than the analytical function. Otherwise you are right.

Comment: using rownum is an overkill too. Since rownum is calculated before ordering. If there's not a primary key column, then better to use considering multiple columns upto be able to reach a uniqueness in the order by clause of row_number() @Volokh.

Answer (score 0):

would LIMIT and OFFSET work? 
ie.

```
SELECT * FROM table
LIMIT 20
OFFSET 20
```

will read rows 20 -> 40. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Oracle does not have LIMIT.

Comment: In that case I would recommend either using FETCH or row_number() as mentioned by Özhan.